# How To Make An ArcGIS 10 Toolbox

Tags: python, arcgis

I'd like to make a new toolbox for ArcGIS 10.

While I have found resources on making Python scripts and the like, I have not yet found any examples or documentation regarding making Toolboxes.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Examples of toolbox codes/setup are much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making a new (empty) toolbox is very easy.

Simply right click on a folder in the Catalog window and choose New | Toolbox.

This is described in the [Online Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/003q/003q00000010000000.htm).

Once you have a toolbox you just right click on that to Add Script and follow the wizard. The help link above should lead you to documentation on all of that.

Pay particular attention to how you define parameters on the tool to correspond with your GetParameterAsText statements in the script.

If you get stuck the [GIS Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com) has many thousands of ArcPy Q&As.